# how to insert zend form values in two tables in zend?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db, zend-db-table, zend-auth

i have two tables `users` and `userslog` where i have `users` contains `id`, `username`,`email`,`gender` and `userslog` contains `id`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`designation` and `u_id` which is `foreign key of users table`.

my register controller

```
class RegisterController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

public function init()
{
    /* Initialize action controller here */
}

public function indexAction()
{

    $form = new Application_Form_register();
    $this->view->form = $form;

    if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    }


}


}
```

my register model is

```
 class Application_Model_DBtable_register extends Zend_Db_Table
{
protected $_name = 'users';
// i have to define two tables here!! how?
}
```

my register zend form

```
class Application_Form_register extends Zend_Form
{
public function init()
{
    $this->setName('register');
    $this->setMethod('post');

    $firstname = $this->createElement('text', 'firstname');
    $firstname->setLabel('FirstName: ')
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->setFilters(array(
                        'stringTrim','StringToLower'));

    $lastname = $this->createElement('text', 'lastname');
    $lastname->setLabel('LastName: ')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->setFilters(array(
                    'stringTrim','StringToLower'));

    $email = $this->createElement('text', 'email');
    $email->setLabel('Email: ')
            ->setRequired(true);

    $username = $this->createElement('text', 'username');
    $username->setLabel('UserName: ')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->setFilters(array(
                    'stringTrim','StringToLower'));

    $password = $this->createElement('password', 'password');
    $password->setLabel('Password: ')
            ->setRequired(true);

    $password2 = $this->createElement('password', 'password2');
    $password2->setLabel('Confirm Password: ')
            ->setRequired(true);

    $submit = $this->createElement('submit', 'register');
    $submit->setLabel('Register')
            ->setIgnore(true);

    $this->addElements(array(
            $firstname,
            $lastname,
            $email,
            $username,
            $password,
            $password2,
            $submit));
}
```

}

how can i do it? can we use Zend_Auth for authentication? if yes then how.please give me example. I saw `$_dependantTable` and `$_referenceMaps` but i can't undestand it . I am confused how to do it because i am not able to define table name more than once in a class. i have to insert the values at same time in two different tables.

Comment: Actually i have plan to add `userlog_id` in `user` and when any one can update some data in `userslog` then a new row is inserted instead of updating the same column. primary id of `userslog` will be inserted in the `userslod_id` in `users` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok this is incorrect:

```
class Application_Model_DBtable_register extends Zend_Db_Table
{
protected $_name = 'users';
// i have to define two tables here!! how?
}
```

The intent of classes that have DbTable in their names is that they they are the adapter/gateway to a single database table.

So your issue would breakdown into at least 2 classes/files:

```
class Application_Model_DBtable_Users extends Zend_Db_Table
{
protected $_name = 'users';
}

class Application_Model_DBtable_Userslog extends Zend_Db_Table
{
protected $_name = 'userslog';
}
```

I would at this level put a method in either class that does the actions required to register a user. Later you may decide to use mappers and domain objects.

```
class Application_Model_DBtable_Users extends Zend_Db_Table
{
    protected $_name = 'users';
    /*
     * psuedocode not meant for production
     */
    public function register($array $data) {
        //sort out the data
        $user = array();//put the elements from the $data array that you want to go into the users table
        $userLog = array(); //same thing for the userslog table
        //get userslog adapter
        $userlogTable = new Application_Model_DbTable_Userslog();
        //do the first insert         
        $result = $this->insert($user);
        //insert returns the primary key of the row created,
        $u_id = array('u_id' => $result);
        $userLog = array_merge($u_id, $userLog); //merge u_id with existing data
        //perform second insert
        $result2 = $userlogTable->insert($userLog);
        //handle any errors
    }
}
```

This should provide a basic example to demonstrate the steps you might take to implement you design. The point behind the DbTable models is to abstract the connection to a given table, each table has it's own DbTable model. The DbTable model provides an adapter to each table and access to the api provided by Zend_Db_Table_Abstract.

The Steps shown above could just as easily be taken in a third model or in the controller itself.

***Note:*** There may be away to do this with one sql statement but I'm not the person who knows that answer.

Comment: thnx. . but if there's an another way to not create different classes for different tables.then please help me!

Comment: There are any number of ways to do this without creating a class for each table. But why bother, it's a simple class that is useful for so many things. If you have a requirement to not use these classes please be more specific as what you need to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

So as to insert values in users and userslog tables, you can try it:

In your RegisterController:

```
$db = new Application_Model_DBtable_register();

$db->instertValuesInUsers(array('column_name' => $data['value'], 'column_name' => $data['value'], ...........));

$db->insertValuesInUserslog(array('column_name' => $data['value'], 'column_name' => $data['value'], ...........));
```

In you Application_Model_DBtable_register:

```
public function instertValuesInUsers(array $data) {
   $this->insert($data);
}

public function insertValuesInUserslog(array $data) {
   $db = new Zend_Db_Table(array('name' => 'userslog'));

   $db->insert($data);
}
```